# Does the Android Gradle plugin support loading native libraries via Maven?

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-ndk

Let's say I have setup the following for all architectures:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.ch-werner</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.9</version>
    <type>so</type>
    <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I have an Android Studio project with a jniLibs dir under the main directory in my app module. Is it possible for the Android Studio plugin to download the so's artifacts from a Maven repo and install them, or is that not yet supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can integrate .so's from a maven artifact.

The proper way to do this is to make an **aar**: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/aar-format

You can put your .so files inside `/jni/<abi>/*.so`,
where `<abi>` is *armeabi*, *armeabi-v7a*, *arm64-v8a*, *x86*, *x86_64*, *mips* and *mips64*, depending on the various android architectures you're supporting.

Comment: i think you are right, I am going to give this a try today. Im using ant but I think i will need to move to maven for the builds

Comment: man, I almost have this, but lets say its harder than it seems to build an AAR using the maven plugin in eclipse